# spring-flex 1.5.2 JUnit test error servletContext null

Tags: servlets, junit4, servletconfig, spring-flex

My project flex 4 + spring-flex 1.5.2 + spring 3.1 + hibernate 3.6(jpa2.0), 
can run in browser, but not work with JUnit4.

**JUnit error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_messageBrokerDefaultHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_messageBroker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: MessageBroker initialization failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at com.wfm.web.TestDao.testGetBaseDao(TestDao.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_messageBroker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: MessageBroker initialization failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:408)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.isSingleton(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1113)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:285)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandlers(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:104)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: MessageBroker initialization failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageBrokerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MessageBrokerFactoryBean.java:207)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.flex.config.FlexConfigurationManager.getMessagingConfiguration(FlexConfigurationManager.java:107)
at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageBrokerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MessageBrokerFactoryBean.java:141)
... 54 more
```

[image: why servletConfig.getServletContext() is null?]

**my persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="welfare" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"/>
```

**my applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.5.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.wfm.web" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:resources.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
        <bean class="org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxoolDataSource">
            <property name="driver" value="${db.driver.class}" />
            <property name="driverUrl" value="${db.url}" />
            <property name="user" value="${db.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
            <property name="maximumConnectionCount" value="${proxool.maxConnCount}" />
            <property name="minimumConnectionCount" value="${proxool.minConnCount}" />
            <property name="statistics" value="${proxool.statistics}" />
            <property name="simultaneousBuildThrottle" value="${proxool.simultaneousBuildThrottle}" />
            <property name="trace" value="${proxool.trace}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="welfare" />
    <property name="persistenceProvider" ref="persistenceProvider" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceProvider" class="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<flex:message-broker />
<bean class="org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter" />
```

**Is there any problem in my config files?**

Answer (score 1):

i put a  comment to `<flex:message-broker />`...it worked fine..
it is unable to find the servletconfig..

Solution 2:
so add the annotation this to your test class

@WebAppConfiguration

Edit 1:
Other Method
You can look at the answer of spring person that is here..http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?74055-Junit4-errors-with-Application-Context-and-BlazeDS

So you need mock web requests in order to get the messagebroker initialization successful.